# for loop for multiple plots of subsets of pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

```
column1       column2    column3    column4   
a            1990        25         A 
b            1990        27         A 
c            1990        24         A
a            1991        26         B
b            1990        20         B
c            1990        20         C
```

so subset where column1 == a should be like

```
column1       column2    column3    column4   
a            1990        25         A 
a            1991        26         B 
a            1990        20         C
```

I wrote a code to generage multiple plots of subset of pandas data frame
subset is the set of rows where the column1 value is same in element of list in sub

```
sub = ['a','b','c','d','e']

for i in sub:
    df_s = df[df['column1']==i]
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    sns.lineplot(x='column2',y='column3', data=df_s, hue='column4',legend=False)
    plt.title("Data of " + p)
plt.show
```

the plots are generated separately with my code. but I want to make it in one figure and only one legend.

Comment: if you move `plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))` before the loop for, then all the lines will be on the same graph, but it will look a bit messy I think. Could you add some input data to see what it looks like

Comment: @Ben.T I edited the question with some example input data

Comment: ok now a question, because you use hue='column4', now you have let's say A blue, B red and C green, this on each plot for a, b, c, d, e. If you want all of them on one plot, how do you see it, somthing like a-A blue, a-B red, a-C green, b-A yellow, b-B orange ... or you want something different? like using markers for each sub, or...?

Comment: No want to see the plot for a, b, c, seperately but in one figure. so the color style? like legend is same at all plots. but each plot only represent the subset of data frame df_s. So what I want to see is 5 plots where the data is df_s, in one figure. My data has 26 elements in sub list so, 26 plots. But when I run that code, all the plots are just in one line and I can't save the all plots in one figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you need to use [FaceGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), here is one way. I used fake data I created

```
sub = ['a','b','c','d','e']
#select just the sub data at once
dfs = df[df['column1'].isin(sub)]

#create the FaceGrid
g = sns.FacetGrid(dfs, 
                  col="column1", 
                  hue='column4', 
                  col_wrap=2, # here it means 2 columns depending on the position you want
                  legend_out=True) 

#lineplot each sub
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'column2', 'column3').add_legend()

#some parameters for titles, axis and legend name if you want to change them
g.set_titles("Data of {col_name}")
g.set_axis_labels(x_var="Maybe something", 
                  y_var="Something else")
g._legend.set_title('name')

#if you want to save the figure
g.savefig('test.png')
```

[image]